# How to write a Cypher query to check commutativity between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to check commutativity between nodes. There are 3 relationships across the node which are tracked as following: aabbca, aabcba, aacbba. Now it is clearly seen that where every b and c node placed together they commute. Below I use the query on how I generate my graph.

Here is my graph:

```
CREATE (x1:Node {title:'a'})

CREATE (x2:Node {title:'a'})

CREATE (x3:Node {title:'b'})

CREATE (x4:Node {title:'b'})

CREATE (x5:Node {title:'c'})

CREATE (x6:Node {title:'a'})

CREATE (x1) - [:transition {id:[1]}] -> (x2)

CREATE (x2) - [:transition {id:[1]}] -> (x3)

CREATE (x3) - [:transition {id:[1]}] -> (x4)

CREATE (x4) - [:transition {id:[1]}] -> (x5)

CREATE (x5) - [:transition {id:[1]}] -> (x6)

CREATE (x1) - [:transition {id:[2]}] -> (x2)

CREATE (x2) - [:transition {id:[2]}] -> (x3)

CREATE (x3) - [:transition {id:[2]}] -> (x5)

CREATE (x5) - [:transition {id:[2]}] -> (x4)

CREATE (x4) - [:transition {id:[2]}] -> (x6)

CREATE (x1) - [:transition {id:[3]}] -> (x2)

CREATE (x2) - [:transition {id:[3]}] -> (x5)

CREATE (x5) - [:transition {id:[3]}] -> (x3)

CREATE (x3) - [:transition {id:[3]}] -> (x4)

CREATE (x4) - [:transition {id:[3]}] -> (x6)
```

That generates something like this:

[image]

Now to clearly identify the commutative nodes, I go ahead and filter on the basis of relationship id 1 & 2, 1 & 3 and 2 & 3 using the following query I get the respective graphs:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) WHERE 1 IN r.id OR 2 In r.id  RETURN a,r,b 
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) WHERE 1 IN r.id OR 3 In r.id  RETURN a,r,b
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) WHERE 2 IN r.id OR 3 In r.id RETURN a,r,b
```

case 1:
[image]
case 2::
[image]
case 3:
[image]

The circled part of **case 2**, for our example has only 2 nodes, but in a generic case it can have 1 *(like we see in **case 1** & **case 3**)* to N number of nodes, where N is a finite number.

Now that's been said, I want to create a cypher query that will check if such commutable node exists or not in the graph and based on that I need to fetch nodes and relationships from a graph using a query like this:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(M)-[r]->(K)-[r]->[b], 
(b)-[s]->(K)-[s]->(M)-[s]->(a)
WHERE r.id <> s.id 
AND M is returning minimum 1 node
AND K is returning minimum 1 node
RETURN a,r,M,K,s,b

K = M 

M = MATCH (O)-[r]->(b1), (N)-[r]->(P)->[s]->(N)
WHERE  
(b1 = b
RETURN b)
OR 
(N = M AND P = M
AND N is returning at least 1 node
AND P is returning at least 1 node 
RETURN N,r,P,s)
```

At this point I might not have defined my constraints clearly but what I need help with is to represent the above query correctly. Can anyone help?

---

Update: 
I just solved for case 1 & case 3 (which are basically same type of condition), but this is not a generic solution. In a generic solution Case 2 would have worked as well.:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)-[s]->(c)-[t]->(d)
WHERE (1 IN r.id OR 2 IN r.id) 
AND (1 IN s.id OR 2 IN s.id) 
AND (1 IN t.id OR 2 IN t.id)
WITH a,r,b,s,c,t,d
MATCH (a)-[r1]->(c)-[s1]->(b)-[t1]->(d)
WHERE ( r <> r1 AND (1 IN r1.id OR 2 IN r1.id)) AND
(s<>s1 AND (1 IN s1.id OR 2 IN s1.id)) AND
(t<>t1 AND (1 IN t1.id OR 2 IN t1.id)) 
RETURN a,r,r1,b,s,s1,c,t,t1,d

MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)-[s]->(c)-[t]->(d)
WHERE (3 IN r.id OR 2 IN r.id) 
AND (3 IN s.id OR 2 IN s.id) 
AND (3 IN t.id OR 2 IN t.id)
WITH a,r,b,s,c,t,d
MATCH (a)-[r1]->(c)-[s1]->(b)-[t1]->(d)
WHERE ( r <> r1 AND (3 IN r1.id OR 2 IN r1.id)) AND
(s<>s1 AND (3 IN s1.id OR 2 IN s1.id)) AND
(t<>t1 AND (3 IN t1.id OR 2 IN t1.id)) 
RETURN a,r,r1,b,s,s1,c,t,t1,d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// A nested loop through the IDs:
UNWIND RANGE(1,3) as i1 WITH i1
    UNWIND RANGE(i1+1,3) as i2 WITH i1, i2

// Take a pathways for each pair of IDs:
MATCH p1 = (N1:Node)-[:transition*5 {id:[i1]}]->(N2:Node), 
      p2 = (N1:Node)-[:transition*5 {id:[i2]}]->(N2:Node)

// Take the nodes of each path:
WITH i1, i2, 
     nodes(p1) as p1, 
     nodes(p2) as p2

WITH i1, i2, p1, p2, 
     // Check whether the nodes are different:
     REDUCE(acc = [], x in RANGE(0, size(p1)-1) | 
            acc + [ { i:x, 
                      is: (p1[x] <> p2[x]) AND 
                          (p1[x]['title'] <> p2[x]['title']) 
                    } ]
     ) as isComm

WITH i1, i2, p1, p2,
     // Take only those nodes that are different: 
     FILTER(pair in isComm WHERE pair['is'] = true) as isComm

RETURN i1 as id1, i2 as id2,
       // Convert a map to an array:
       REDUCE(acc = [], pair in isComm | 
              acc + [ [ p1[pair['i']], 
                        p2[pair['i']]
                    ] ] 
       ) as commutative
```